# Dynamic reports -set width and height of report

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I want to print a report to a smaller paper size. Default seems to be A4, but I want to print in a paper size nearly half of A4.

How can we setthe width and height of the printed output in dynamic reports? Is it possible to set the height adjust to its contents automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that it is possible to set the output size using the following method:

```
JasperReportBuilder.setPageFormat(200, 500, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: are the integers in milimeters?