# How to set page width in Dynamic report?

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I am using dynamic report to generate report.

I have as much as 15 columns to be displayed in the report.

Since the dynamic report is by default displaying A4 size page,the contents are too cumbersome to read.

Can any one suggest which is the best way to increase the page width?

Comment: The answer to your question can found [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322129/dynamic-reports-set-width-and-height-of-report

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setPageFormat(width, height, orientation);` 
example : `report.(200, 230, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT)` .